# NullPointerException in Java with BlueJ

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bluej

When I try to call the method BuyItem, so that the class Rebel can buy an item from the class Item, I get this message:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

I feel like I´ve been trying everything, do somebody see what´s wrong in the code?

Here are my methods:

```
public boolean buyItem(Item item) {
    int totalWeight = currentWeight() + item.getWeight();
    if(totalWeight <= maxCarryingCapacity && money >= item.getPrice()){
        money -= item.getPrice();
        backpack.put(item.getName(), item);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @param item
 * @return current carrying weight
 */
private int currentWeight() {
    int tempWeight = 0;
    for(Entry<String, Item> entry: backpack.entrySet()) {
        tempWeight += entry.getValue().getWeight();
    }
    return tempWeight;
}
```

I would be really happy if anyone of you could help me, since im stuck!

It is the second line in currentWeight and first line in buyItem that gets the error. The terminal window shows:

```
rebel1.buyItem(item1)
Exception occurred.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at Rebel.currentWeight(Rebel.java:190)
at Rebel.buyItem(Rebel.java:56)
```

Comment: What line is the exception on? I'm assuming item isn't null. Or is it?

Comment: First of all, add your full exception stacktrace and full source code where the crash occur. We can't help you with just partial code.

Comment: Yeah, we're gonna need more to go on here. There's a lot of stuff that could be null here.

Comment: Well, really, there are two likely candidates for null: backpack and item. I'm guessing it's backpack since it shows up in both methods.

Comment: I hope you got the information you need now:)

Comment: On stackoverflow, the RPG tag means the RPG programming language.  Please read tag info before using, if you are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Did you initialize the `backpack` variable/attribute? You should also check to not pass `null` for the item in `buyItem()`.

Comment: Would be really useful if you could point out which line in `currentWeight()` is line 190.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely looks like backpack hasn't been initialised. It might be worth using a constructor like

```
public class Rebel{
    private final Map<String, Item> backpack;
    public Rebel(Map<String, Item> backpack, <Other parameters){
        this.backpack = backpack;
    }
    public Rebel(<Other parameters>){
        this(new HashMap<String,Item>(),<Other parameters>);
    }
}
```

Obviously replacing `<Other parameters>` with your current constructor parameters.